# Java JDT UI: How to infix expression from a VariableDeclarationStatement

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I have been stuck on a particular problem that is to extract an infixexpression from a VariableDeclarationStatement. for example:

String s = 'a'+'b'+'c';

This is an instance of VariableDeclarationStatement. and i need to get the infixexpression `'a'+'b'+'c'` out of it.

**I have tried :** 1.Tried converting to string.But no conversion back is possible.

2.Tried converting to list but still not possible.

I have tried above methods to try and manipulate and extract InfixExpression out of it.Please help me.

**EDIT**

here is what i have done :

```
   if (node instanceof InfixExpression) {
        infixExpression= (InfixExpression) node;
    } else if (node.getParent() instanceof InfixExpression) {
        infixExpression= (InfixExpression) node.getParent();
    } else {            //while trying to get this proposal with spaces its reaching here.
        String nodeString =node.toString();
        String infixExp="s";
        int t;
    for (t=0;nodeString.charAt(t)!='=';t++);

        infixExp.concat(nodeString.substring(t+1, nodeString.length()));
        infixExpression = (InfixExpression)infixExp;            //this cast doesn't work here

    }
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: @ehh I have a code snippet where i'am trying to convert the node to string and then extract the infixexpression and then convert it back. but that conversion doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry Java is not my territory. Just ask you to post so other could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Its still unclear what you want to do.

```
public class InfixVisitor extends ASTVisitor {
    @Override
    public boolean visit(InfixExpression node) {
        // NOTE: node.toString() should only be used debugging.
        // Probably you could use it anyway.
        ...
        return super.visit(node);
    }
}
```

With above visitor you can access all `InfixExpression` nodes with e.g.:

```
ASTNode sourceNode = ...
sourceNode.accept(new InfixVisitor());
```